# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I am Getting this error Please solve this.
Error - java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface javax.xml.transform.Source. Registering an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.

So Please try to fix this error.

I am getting this error when I am try to fetch data from the Newsapi.org by using the Retrofit.

```
package com.example.newapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.example.newapp.Models.NewsApiResponse;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Query;

public class RequestManager {

    Context context;

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://newsapi.org/v2/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    public void getNewsHeadlines(OnFetchDataListener listener, String category, String query){

        CallNewsApi callNewsApi = retrofit.create(CallNewsApi.class);
        Call<NewsApiResponse> call = callNewsApi.callheadlines("techcrunch","9d12903806bd47c2b5e70d25cd09c9ca");

        try{
            call.enqueue(new Callback<NewsApiResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<NewsApiResponse> call, Response<NewsApiResponse> response) {

                    Log.d("RES", response.toString());

                    if(!response.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Error!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    listener.onFetchData(response.body().getArticles(), response.message());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<NewsApiResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    listener.onError("Request Failed");

                    Log.d("ERROR-RESPONSE", t.toString());
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public RequestManager(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public interface CallNewsApi {
        @GET("top-headlines")
        Call<NewsApiResponse> callheadlines (
                @Query("sources") String source,
                @Query("apikey") String api_key
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please include the code of your `NewsApiResponse` class and any class it is referencing with its fields? The exception sounds like you have a field of type `javax.xml.transform.Source` somewhere, and Gson provides no default adapter to construct it from JSON.